# Substring from object Get-ChildItem Name PSParentPath Table Output

Tags: powershell, substring, display, get-childitem

Acknowledged that I am a Powershell Rookie ...

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    select-object -property Name, Attributes, PSParentPath
```

Gives table format output and data as desired, but looking to so-called substring the `PSParentPath` property output to truncate / remove the first 38 characters from 0 index (starting character) with resultant table view of and or "`Export-Csv`" file.

I have tried assigning a string VAR to the `PSParentPath` and manipulate the output - which I am able to redact / remove the first 38 characters of the resultant `PSParentPath` string value.  But the output of all values (`Name, Attributes, $PSParentPath.substring(38)`) are returned / displayed as individual line items in the CMD Prompt instead of in the following desired table format;

```
Name                 Attributes            PSParentPath
---------           -----------            -----------
Filename1               Archive            C:\temp\
DirectoryName1          Directory          C:\temp\DirectoryName1
```

Versus not desired result: (seemingly random order from my limited understanding)

```
Filename1
DirectoryName1
Archive
C:\temp\
Directory
C:\temp\DirecotryName1
```

Comment: JosefZ has done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Comment: What's wrong on `Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
select-object -property Name, Attributes, FullName`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3#select-object) in this case:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-Object Name, Attributes, @{ N = 'PSParentPath'; E= { $_.PSParentPath.SubString(38) }}
```

Another approach that doesn't require string manipulation:

```
$expression = {
    if ($_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
        return $_.DirectoryName
    }

    $_.Parent.FullName
}

Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-Object Name, Attributes, @{ N = 'ParentPath'; E = $expression }
```

Comment: Thank You for the prompt answer and advice of Post Format. First time on this support Forum.